# ¿Cómo mostrar la url de una imagen con python discord bot?

Tags: python, discord.py

Estoy creando un pequeño bot en python, y tengo un pequeño problema: quiero que el bot me muestre la url y no sé cómo hacerlo.

Este es el código que estoy usando actualmente:

```
with io.BytesIO() as image_binary:
          img1.save(image_binary, 'PNG')
          image_binary.seek(0)
          embed=discord.Embed(title="Skin Minecraft", url="https://twitter.com/", description=f"", color=discord.Colour.random())
        
          embed.set_image(url=f"attachment://Skin-{usuariominecraft}.png")
               
          await ctx.send(embed=embed, file=discord.File(fp=image_binary, filename=f"Skin-{usuariominecraft}.png"))
```

Ejemplo de lo que quiero que me muestre:

```
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1050554950377295932/1051179097558106334/Skin-evilafm.png
```

Comment: Creo que el objeto `discord.File` tiene una propiedad `url` solo tendrías que acceder a ese atributo.

Comment: Cómo lo hago, soy algo nuevo con esto

Comment: `file=discord.File(fp=image_binary, filename=f"Skin-{usuariominecraft}.png"); url = file.url`

Comment: no me funciona.

Comment: Edita la pregunta con el nuevo código que tienes y si hay errores en la consola también ponlos